# Python Scrapy not outputting to csv file

Tags: python, scrapy

What am I doing wrong with the script so it's not outputting a csv file with the data? I am running the script with `scrapy runspider yellowpages.py -o items.csv` and still nothing is coming out but a blank csv file. I have followed different things here and also watched youtube trying to figure out where I am making the mistake and still cannot figure out what I am not doing correctly.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import requests

search = "Plumbers"
location = "Hammond, LA"
url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search"
q = {'search_terms': search, 'geo_location_terms': location}
page = requests.get(url, params=q)
page = page.url
items = ()


class YellowpagesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['yellowpages.com']
    start_urls = [page]

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log("I just visited: " + response.url)
        items = response.css('a[class=business-name]::attr(href)')
        for item in items:
            print(item)
```

Comment: You need to `return` the items, not `print` them.  Returned values are captured by Scrapy, and will be output as per your `-o items.csv` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple spider without project.

Use my code, I wrote comments to make it easier to understand. This spider looks for all blocks on all pages for a pair of parameters "service" and "location". To run, use:

In your case:

> scrapy runspider yellowpages.py -a servise="Plumbers" -a location="Hammond, LA" -o Hammondsplumbers.csv

The code will also work with any queries. For example:

> scrapy runspider yellowpages.py -a servise="Doctors" -a location="California, MD" -o MDDoctors.json

etc...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider


class YellowpagesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yellowpages'
    allowed_domains = ['yellowpages.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.yellowpages.com/']

    # We can use any pair servise + location on our request
    def __init__(self, servise=None, location=None):
        self.servise = servise
        self.location = location

    def parse(self, response):
        # If "service " and" location " are defined 
        if self.servise and self.location:
            # Create search phrase using "service" and " location"
            search_url = 'search?search_terms={}&geo_location_terms={}'.format(self.servise, self.location)
            # Send request with url "yellowpages.com" + "search_url", then call parse_result
            yield Request(url=response.urljoin(search_url), callback=self.parse_result)
        else:
            # Else close our spider
            # You can add deffault value if you want.
            self.logger.warning('=== Please use keys -a servise="service_name" -a location="location" ===')
            raise CloseSpider()

    def parse_result(self, response):
        # all blocks without AD posts
        posts = response.xpath('//div[@class="search-results organic"]//div[@class="v-card"]')
        for post in posts:
            yield {
                'title': post.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract_first(),
                'url': response.urljoin(post.xpath('.//a[@class="business-name"]/@href').extract_first()),
            }

        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@class="next ajax-page"]/@href').extract_first()
        # If we have next page url
        if next_page:
            # Send request with url "yellowpages.com" + "next_page", then call parse_result
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse_result)
```

Comment: Is there another way to contact you other than here? I have more questions about this code and how I can make it work further but i don't want to clog up this.

Comment: Telegram: @Nozent

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

put yield instead of print there,

```
for item in items:
    yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

On inspection of your code, I notice a number of problems:

First, you initialize `items` to a tuple, when it should be a list: `items = []`.

You should change your `name` property to reflect the name you want on your crawler so you can use it like so: `scrapy crawl my_crawler` where `name = "my_crawler"`.

`start_urls` is supposed to contain strings, not `Request` objects. You should change the entry from `page` to the exact search string you want to use. If you have a number of search strings and want to iterate over them, I would suggest using a [middleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html).

When you try to extract the data from CSS you're forgetting to call `extract_all()` which would actually transform your selector into string data which you could use.

Also, you shouldn't be redirecting to the standard output stream because a lot of logging goes there and it'll make your output file really messy. Instead, you should extract the responses into [items](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html) using [loaders](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html).

Finally, you're probably missing the appropriate settings from your `settings.py` file. You can find the relevant documentation [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-format-csv).

```
FEED_FORMAT = "csv"
FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS = ["Field 1", "Field 2", "Field 3"]
```